# How to force `protocol://` redirection in a web page like Discord server invitation link?

Tags: javascript, html, discord

I'm looking to create a `protocol://` redirection like a Discord server invitation link.

Context:

I'm developing in an environment where only HTTP protocol is allowed (S&box engine). So i cannot use `steam://` protocol directly for example.

After investigation, i found that a Discord invitation link is correctly working (like `https://discord.com/invite/XXXX`): the internal web browser will open it. And then, if the Discord desktop application is launched, it will show automatically the new Server joined. This is the wanted behavior.

So I have to use a self-hosted webpage in order to open a custom protocol.

In order to reproduce this Discord behavior with a simple hosted web page, i have written something like this :

```
<script>
    window.location.href = "steam://openurl_external/https://facepunch.com/"
</script>
```

But once my page is loaded with the internal web browser of S&box nothing occurs. However, this works well in a classic web browser (like Chrome/Firefox/Edge...)

By ignoring my specific developing context (cause this works well with Discord invitation link), does anyone know how Discord manages to open a local protocol in order to automatically open Discord application through a webpage ?

By looking at the javascript/html web page code of Discord invite link, it doesn't seem to use any `href=discord://` protocol.

Regards

Comment: Discord seems to use a WebSocket connection to the launched Discord application. Then after connection, it tells the application to be the focused window on Windows.